# Spring controller returning object to client

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, jhipster

A JHipster generated Spring and Angular project has a generated controller and endpoint to get a single Plan entity by Id and return it to the browser client.

Plan has a one to many relationship with Task. The relationship was setup also in Jhipster.

The issue is that I have now created a endpoint to retrieve a new Plan entity which also has a list of associated tasks but even after modifying the Angular to use the new endpoint no plan is now getting displayed in the browser.

Please comment if not enough of the project is shared to determine the issue.

**Controllers**

```
@GetMapping("/plans/{id}") // JHIPSTER GENERATED METHOD
public ResponseEntity<PlanDTO> getPlan(@PathVariable Long id) {
    Optional<PlanDTO> planDTO = planService.findOne(id);
    return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(planDTO);
}

@GetMapping("/plantask/{id}") // NEW METHOD FOR PLANTASKDTO
public PlanTaskViewDTO getTaskAndPlanByPlanId(@PathVariable Long id) {
    log.debug("REST request to get Plan and Tasks by Plan id : {}", id);
    PlanTaskViewDTO planTaskViewDTO = planService.createPlanTaskViewDTO(id);
    return planTaskViewDTO;
}
```

Below is the find method in the plan.service.ts with a updated resourcePlanTaskURL for the new endpoint, and the is passed into the find method:

**plan.service.ts**

```
type EntityResponseType = HttpResponse<IPlan>;
type EntityArrayResponseType = HttpResponse<IPlan[]>;
    
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PlanService {
      public resourceUrl = SERVER_API_URL + 'api/plans';
      public resourceSearchUrl = SERVER_API_URL + 'api/_search/plans';
      public resourcePlanTaskUrl = SERVER_API_URL + 'api/plantask';         // NEW URL

constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {}
    find(id: number): Observable<EntityResponseType> {
    return this.http
      .get<IPlan>(`${this.resourcePlanTaskUrl}/${id}`, { observe: 'response' })
      .pipe(map((res: EntityResponseType) => this.convertDateFromServer(res)));
   }
```

**plan-detail.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { IPlan } from 'app/shared/model/plan.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'jhi-plan-detail',
  templateUrl: './plan-detail.component.html',
})
export class PlanDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  plan: IPlan | null = null;

  constructor(protected activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ plan }) => (this.plan = plan));
  }

  previousState(): void {
    window.history.back();
  }
}
```

**plan.route.ts**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PlanResolve implements Resolve<IPlan> {
  constructor(private service: PlanService, private router: Router) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<IPlan> | Observable<never> {
    const id = route.params['id'];
    if (id) {
      return this.service.find(id).pipe(
        flatMap((plan: HttpResponse<Plan>) => {
          if (plan.body) {
            return of(plan.body);     // BROWSER BREAKPT - THIS LINE DOES RETURN PLANTASK
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['404']);
            return EMPTY;
          }
        })
      );
    }
    return of(new Plan());
  }
}
...<snip routes>
```

**plan-detail.component.html**

```
  <div *ngIf="plan">
  <h2><span>Plan</span> {{ plan.id }}</h2>    // NOTHING DISPLAYED
```

Browser inspection shows that planTaskDTO data is passed from the backend to the client using the new endpoint api/plantask.

Q: What other changes are to be made so that the browser still will display PlanTaskDTO? (Using the HTML fragment above I would at least expect to still see plan id)

Comment: You seem to be taking the "plan" from the activated route, shouldn't you be taking it from the PlanService instead?

Comment: @SrThompson using the activated route was working with just Plan. I have posted a snip of the plan.route.ts module.

Comment: You should always start by tracing your operation one step at a time. Examine your browser's Network tab to see what request it's making and what response it's getting.